# FirebaseUI FirestoreRecyclerAdapter - Get DocumentReference to delete it

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

What is the correct way to delete an item from the `Firebase-UI` RecyclerView for `Firestore`?

This is my approach:

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

private void deleteItem(int position) {
    DocumentSnapshot ds = (DocumentSnapshot) adapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
    DocumentReference document = ds.getReference();
    document.delete();
}
```

Why does `getSnapshot` return an `Object` and not a `DocumentSnapshot`? Is the cast to `(DocumentSnapshot)` correct?

Also is it correct that I don't have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemRemoved` because the adapter already reacts to changes in the database?

Comment: Do you want to delete the item completely from your database or only from your adapter?

Comment: I want to delete it from the Firestore database as well

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, if you want to delete an item from the database, then you should use `delete()` method directly on the `DocumentReference` object.

```
db.collection("YourCollection").document("DocumentToDelete")
    .delete()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
        }
    });
```

Because you are using Firebase-UI, this change will be automatically seen, without the use of this method call:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please also note that deleting a document does not delete its subcollections, if you have some.

Comment: Thank you but I want to get the DocumentReference out of the adapter.

Comment: I don't understand you. Once you delete a document from the database is also deleted from the adapter, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: The FirebaseUI Adapter takes a `Query` as it's input, which means that I didn't have a reference to any of the documents beforehand. From the adapter position I want to get a reference to the clicked item, which apparently is accomplished by `adapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What does `adapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position)` return?

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: As a noob I was wondering why it returns `Object` and not `DocumentSnapshot` but it changes when I put it into the adapter rather than outside of it.

Comment: Every class in Java is an `Object` because every class extends `Object` class. So if your object is of type `DocumentSnapshot` you can cast it then to `DocumentSnapshot`, right?

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you for the initial question, for deleting a document?

Comment: Yes but we don't design every class to return an object and then cast it, so I ask for the reason.

Comment: Ya, you're right, I just wanted to tell this option.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is to create a Firebase-UI-Adapter like so:

```
public class YourFirestoreAdapter extends 
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<YourClass, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

//complete the method here for the Adapter, like you would a normal Recycle adapter.
```

Then after the onCreateViewHolder method add a method to delete an item like so (Within your Adapter):

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
        }
```

Then call this method from your activity whenever you want to delete an item, by passing the position from your ItemTouchHelper.

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new 
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
 viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```